# XOrg - AMDGPU Failed to make 16bpp pixmap exportable

Tags: centos, xorg, xfce, freeze, amd

**Intro**

I've recently acquired a new desktop from Dell which comes with an AMD setup: AMD Ryzen 3 1200 Quad-Core Processor with Radeon RX 460.

It came from Dell with Ubuntu installed but i've wiped this out and installed Centos 7.4.

**Problem**

My current issue is that sometimes my desktop (Xfce4) is freezing (apparently) at random.

**Drivers/Configs**

- I'm currently using the **amdgpu** that i've downloaded from the official homepage
- My Xorg setup: `20-amdgpu.conf`

  `Section "Device"
          Identifier "My GPU"
          Driver "amdgpu"
  EndSection`

**Logs and Notes**

- I've notice that sometimes both my keyboard and mouse stops emitting - light like the USB stopped providing energy but the LEDs of the PC itself are still on with the CPU and GPU fan on. Other times this doesn't happen. Keyboard and mouse are emitting lights but the desktop (Xfce4) still not responds.
- One other thing is that this happens almost always when i get idle while browsing (Firefox Quantum or Chrome) or using Android Studio.
- I've tried open Dota 2 and let the PC idle but i got back without any freezing issues.
- finally i was looking at the xorg error logs and got this:

`[  2680.718] (EE) AMDGPU(0): Failed to make 16bpp pixmap exportable`

This log was repeated for at least 20 more times and this is the last entry on the error logs right after it frozen up while coding on Android Studio.

**Well**

Not sure if this is just one single issue related to this single log line. I've researched that the **amdgpu** driver is causing a variety of troubles on other distros and setups. So my final questions ares:

1. Is this error log a knowing issue that i can (try to) fix and retests the freezing?
2. Or this random freezes are another thing?
3. What more i can do to come debug this kind of issue?

Thanks a lot guys :)